# Get files off iPhone (iPad/iPod/etc) without using the Internet?

Tags: itunes, file-transfer, iphone, ipad, ipod

My daughter had a school assignment where she needed to talk to someone in Spanish and send a recording to her school.  I used my iPhone, the files are too big to email, and am trying to figure out how to get them to her teacher.  There are "cloud" solutions, but my wife has concerns, and don't disagree if one wants to ensure privacy.  My daughter just now came up to me and said "why don't we just video record your iPhone", and while not a bad idea, still feel there has got to be a better way.

How can I get files off an iPhone without using the Internet?

Comment: grab them from your computer and use removable media

Comment: @Tim  And how do I do that?  Grab them, that is.  Can't seem to do so from Windows Explorer.  iTunes doesn't seem to present any opportunity.  If need be, I could go down some Linux path, but would rather take care of this simply.

Comment: [Apple](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201302) has a nice write up on how to do this.

Comment: @Tim  Ah, it was the "Trust this computer" part I was missing.  All good.  Thanks